# Stably expansivity of $f(x)=mx$, $|m|>1$.

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined by
\begin{equation*}
  f(x)= \left(%
\begin{array}{cc}
  \lambda & 0 \\
  0 & n\lambda \\
\end{array}%
\right) x, 
\end{equation*}
where $\lambda>0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$

It is easy to see that $f$ is expansive, this means that there is $c>0$ such that if $d(f^n(x), f^n(y))<c$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $x=y$.

What can say about homeomorphisms that are closed to $f$? i.e. is there is $\delta>0$ such that if $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ is a homeomorphism with $d(f(x), g(x))<\delta$, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $g$ is an expansive homeomorphism?

Comment: I am a bit confused. If I pick $\lambda=1$, then your map is not expansive. Is it?

Comment: In case your $d$ is the $C^1$-distance, then it should be true as the partial derivatives are strict between $0<c$ and $C<1$, or strictly bigger $\tilde{C}>1$ (depending whether $\lambda\in (0,1)$ or $\lambda >1$) and then your claim follows from the mean value theorem.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, Thanks, Yes, $\lambda\neq 1$. What can say about $d_0(f, g):=\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^2}\{ d(f(x), g(x)), d(f^{-1}(x), g^{-1}(x))\}$?

Comment: No, I think the $C^0$ topology will not save you. Just change the function around the origin slightly, such that it has fixed points there. Then the map will not be expansive.